# How to $match two lists using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have collection as:
**col1**

```
{"_id":"5c3ea35651166f3refsfd5",
"environment": "production",
"application": ['cloud', 'android', 'finance']},

{"_id":"5c3ea35651166f3refsfd6",
"environment": "production",
"application": ['banking', 'network', 'finance']}
```

I want to project the data only if the application/s in collection matches with the application in the list of **['cloud', 'database', 'booking']**. In this case, I should be able to get only first document as it has '***cloud***' in both document as well as in list.

I need to use aggregation. But I am not getting correct direction..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) query operator

```
col1.aggregate([
  { '$match': { 'application': { '$in': ['cloud', 'database', 'booking'] }}},
  { '$project': { 'environment': 1, 'application':1 }}
])
```

Comment: But the values in list changes according to user, so I should not use fixed list.

Comment: You can dynamically put the `lst` array.

Comment: Oh! my bad. Thank you.